# GeoServer Layer Preview Opens OpenLayers instead of GeoExplorer

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I am using OpenGeo 3.0 and trying to get GeoExplorer to launch through the Layer Preview. I imported PostGIS tables into GeoServer and created a layer.  However, when I go to view the layer and select "GeoExplorer-->Go", it opens OpenLayers.  Is there something I need to configure?.

Comment: I just tried this with 3.0.2 in Safari and it works fine. I do remember that there was an issue with the Layer Preview dropdown - maybe it was fixed between 3.0 and 3.0.2. Would an upgrade be an option for you?

Comment: An upgrade is an option but not an easy one in the government.  It will be about a 1 month process.  I will look into this.

Comment: By the way, the title for this question was originally wrong. I changed the question I was asking and forgot to change the title, but it is now correct.

Comment: Fortunately OpenGeo 3.1 was already approved and I upgraded.  Unfortunately, it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a support ticket w/ OpenGeo and they determined it's a bug and are submitting a bug report.  The problem only occurs w/ IE8 on Win 7, at least for me.  When I tested on Chrome, everything worked fine.  This has apparently been an issue since at least v3.0.2 and still exists in v3.1.  I do not know if this is an issue w/ all installations of IE8 on Win 7 or if my workstation configuration contributed something else to prevent the IE8/Win 7 combination from working.

Comment: Ken, do you have the OpenGeo support ticket reference so that we can track the resolution of this issue? Thanks

Comment: @Herve, the ticket number was 1920.